# Webpack/Babel es2015 error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

after looking at the possible solutions for the issue i had, couldn't find a way to solve this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Im stuck at this point and cant seem to solve it (feel a bit restless when trying to learn and work).

P.S. I appreciate your time and help. Im relatively a new developer, pardon me if i have asked anything stupid. thanks

For your expert review, here's the relevant files that im working with:

**package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.6",
    "browsersync": "0.0.1-security",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jquery-smooth-scroll": "^2.1.2",
    "lazysizes": "^3.0.0-rc3",
    "normalize.css": "^5.0.0",
    "picturefill": "^3.0.2",
    "waypoints": "^4.0.1"
 },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-modernizr": "^1.0.0-alpha",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rev": "^7.1.2",
    "gulp-svg-sprite": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-svg2png": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.11",
    "postcss-hexrgba": "^0.2.1",
    "postcss-import": "^9.1.0",
    "postcss-mixins": "^5.4.1",
    "postcss-nested": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-simple-vars": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
 module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./app/assets/scripts/App.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: "./app/temp/scripts",
    filename: "App.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        },
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import MobileMenu from './modules/MobileMenu';


var mobileMenu = new MobileMenu();
```

**MobileMenu.js**

```
class MobileMenu {
  constructor() {
    alert("testing 123")
  }
}

export default MobileMenu;
```

> **scripts.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
webpack = require('webpack');

gulp.task('scripts', ['modernizr'], function(callback) {
  webpack(require('../../webpack.config.js'), function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.toString());
    }
    console.log(stats.toString());
    callback();
  });
});
```

Comment: How are you running it? You don't have any scripts in `package.json` so I can't really tell, but you need to run webpack and then run the generated bundle.

Comment: im running it from script.js ! @MichaelJungo

Comment: That compiles it and generates the bundle at `app/temp/scripts/App.js`. Are you including that file in your HTML or the original source?

Comment: u r right. I included the bundled file at temp/scripts/App.js now and that solves it. as i can see i dont even require .babelrc file in the project. awesome, i appreciate ur help man thanks a lot @MichaelJungo

Comment: @MichaelJungo add your comment as an answer and let solu mark it as the solution

Answer (score -1):

> **Solution**

As it seems that it doesnt really matter which version of the babel core, babel-loader we actually use. Also .babelrc file was not required for me. What worked for me was to include the bundled file in my HTML which was generated at `temp/scripts/App.js`, instead of including the original source at `assets/scripts/App.js`. Thats it ! cheers

Thanks to @MichaelJungo